# Form not save with custom form fields

Tags: python, django

Good morning guys, I have a problem with a form.

My code:

`models.py`

```
class AnagraficaGenerale(models.Model):
    ragionesociale = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    cf = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    piva = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
```

`forms.py`

```
class AnagraficaGeneraleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = AnagraficaGenerale
        fields = '__all__'
```

`views.py`

```
@login_required
def anagrafica_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AnagraficaGeneraleForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('anagrafica_list')
    else:
        form = AnagraficaGeneraleForm()
    return render(request, 'Anagrafiche/anagrafica_new.html', {'form': form})
```

`html`

```
{% extends 'FBIsystem/basenobar.html' %}
{%load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}

    <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="panel">
<div class="panel-body">
  <h3 class="title-hero">
    Nuova Anagrafica
</h3>
    <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal bordered-row">
                {% csrf_token %}
                 <div class="example-box-wrapper">

  <div class="form-group">

           <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" > Ragione Sociale:</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
             {{ form.ragionesociale }}
                    </div>

                 </div>
</div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salva</button>
   </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Everything seems ok but not save, if I try with {{form.as_table}} it save. 
I think there is a problem with custom field but I don't know how.

whats wrong?

TY

Comment: Does `AnagraficaGenerale` model have only one field?

Comment: no, but it's the same

Comment: I think your form is not valid. Try print out form errors. e.g `if form.is_valid(): ... else: print(form.errors) print(form.non_field_errors)`

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't save? Copied and pasted your code and it worked as expected: The new instance was saved.

Comment: TY @kyore , i founded the error.